# Coffee spider web score

Tags: bean-varieties, tasting

I have been purchasing unroasted green coffee beans for a while now, and they all seem to have this spider web looking diagram representing a composite score of some sort of the coffee.  [this](https://www.sweetmarias.com/product/tanzania-isende-fbg) link has an example of what I am talking about (fourth listed image).  Does anyone know how to interpret these scores.  Also, what does "Cupper's Correction" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph shown is a spider-web graph that is similar to a line graph but in a shape of a spider web. In this case, the scale (middle line, goes from bottom to top) shows the score each section can get. A blue line (or any color) is drawn according to the scale. A score closer to six will have its vertex nearer to the center of the web and a score nearer to 10 will be nearer to the outside. This graph seems to be scoring the different qualities of the coffee.

A Cupper's Correction is used when the grapher thinks that the total score (add all the smaller ones) should be higher or lower. In this case, it's two so the original total score has two bonus points.

Source for Cupper's Correction: http://legacy.sweetmarias.com/library/content/cuppers-correction

Quote:

> The cupper's correction is a term we use to measure the intangible qualities of a cup: if, for instance, a coffee totals 88 points, but it is high quality enough that we feel it should< be a 90, we add in a +2 cupper's correction.

I think the "<" in the quote is a typo.